# i wanted to play .mp4 video in windows phone 7.5 but it doesn't work with PHP

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, mp4

I have coded it for android and Iphone but it doesn't work in Windows Phone 7.5.
I search into forums but I've found nothing.

the device opens the player but doesn't load video.

I don't know what headers are needed, any idea?

my code for android is this:

```
$file

$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');

$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;

    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$outname);


$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();
}

fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7.5 supports the MP4 container with the following codecs ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)):

- AAC-LC
- AAC+
- eAAC+

You should try to open the video and debug on the Desktop version of IE9 (it has the same codebase as Mobile IE9).

Comment: the video works if I load it with a header(location), but my videos are hosted in a private area, not accessible via location.

Comment: nothing.... the video player open but say "dont open/play the archive" and close the player... :(